# How can I get value of tags with hyphen in python with bs4?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am using a python with module bs4 for my school project and I have a problem in one part. I want to get a value from tag but this tag contains dash (-). I couldn't figure out it. Obviously, I got syntax error:

> SyntaxError : keyword can't be an expression

```
...
...
print(papers[0].find("a", abc-xyz = True)["abc-xyz"])
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: why are you doing `abc-xyz = True`? What is the expected result and how does the tag look like in the page?

Comment: <a href="url" abc-xyz="someuniquecode" data-bind="click> this is an example of html code that I wanted to handle.Basicly, I want to find a <a> tag with <abc-xyz> tag and take it's value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd bet you are looking for a  tag that looks like this

```
<a abc-xyz="True" href="http://www.example.com">
```

if I'm right, then you want

```
the_tag = .find("a", {"abc-xyz" : True})
value_of_abc_xyz = the_tag['abc-xyz']
```

Answer (score 0):

`abc` and `xyz` in your code are being used expression (subtraction) and being set to `True`, which is wrong.

And then you're trying to locate `"abc-xyz"`.

All you have to do is fix `abc-xyz = True` with proper attributes. Check out [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#find(name,%20attrs,%20recursive,%20text,%20**kwargs)).

e.g.

```
print(papers[0].find("a", {"abc-xyz": True})["abc-xyz"])
```